# X11 forwarding fails every 20-30 minutes

Tags: ssh, x11, osx-elcapitan, x11-forwarding, xquartz

I have XQuartz 2.7.9 installed on OS X 10.11.5 and I'm able to successfully ssh with X11 forwarding to Linux machines. At first, I can open X11 windows without a problem. However, after about 20-30 minutes I cannot open any additional X11 windows. The X11 windows I already have open are fine.

With one Linux machine I get the error: "Fatal IO error: client killed". And on another Linux machine I get the error: "Cannot connect to X server".

I've tried messing with the value of ConnectTimeout in /etc/ssh/ssh_config, thinking that this might help, but it didn't. As of now, what I'm doing is exiting the current ssh session and then re-sshing. This gets real annoying, real quick.

Answer (score 1):

ForwardX11Timeout = 500h
in /etc/ssh/ssh_config